# ASP.NET Core 1.1 Web API not working on Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I created an ASP.NET CORE web application using Visual Studio 2017 Community. On it I have the usual controllers (Manage, Home, Account) plus a few of my own.

My API TestController has so far only two methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetSitemap()
{
    Request.Headers.Clear();
    Request.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/xml");
    System.Xml.Linq.XDocument gsmXML = GoogleSitemap.AutoSeek(Domain);
    return new ContentResult()
        {
            StatusCode = 200,
            ContentType = "application/xml",
            Content = gsmXML.ToString()
        };
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetSiteName()
{
    return new OkObjectResult( "Test API");
}
```

Now, I wanted to also add a Web API to my web application, somebody suggests using an AREA for the API which is just fine. So I created an area named API for all API controllers.

```
   ~/Areas/
        API/
           Controllers/
               TestController.cs
           _ViewImports.cshtml
           _ViewStart.cshtml
```

And my route definition in Startup.cs looks like this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
    routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areaRoute",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Dashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

The problem is when I make a request to my API method I get an empty page:

```
      localhost:1234/api/Test/GetSitemap
```

and for what I see the breakpoint does not trigger on the GetSitemap API method.
But when I change the request to:

```
      localhost:1234/api/Test/
```

Then I get an exception saying something about ambitguous because two methods matched. They both start with Get but the route specified Get (and Get alone) as the default so I do not see why GetSitemap and GetSiteName match.

If I remove the GetSiteName API method then the ambiguous exception does not happen but I am shown a page with the results of GetSitemap which is wrong because the default action is Get and not GetSitemap.

Answer (score 0):

Method names are not related to the api routes. You currently have two calls that are on the same route, which is the default controller route:

```
localhost:1234/api/Test/
```

You can define the routes of methods by editing your `HttpGet` tags to the following:

```
[HttpGet("GetSitemap")]
public IActionResult GetSitemap()
{
    ...
}

[HttpGet("GetSiteName")]
public IActionResult GetSiteName()
{
    ...
}
```